# What is the backstory of the knife in Jeeper Creepers 2?

Tags: plot-explanation, jeeper-creepers-2

In [***Jeeper Creepers 2***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0301470/) (2003), the elder brother gets a knife from the field, which was probably accidentally dropped by the creeper when it took the younger boy. The elder brother took it to the father to have a look at it.

When the father is looking at the knife it falls out of his hands and hits the wooden wall as if he threw it.

Why did it fly out of his hand?

I don't remember the movie going into it, but does anyone know more about it from the movie extras?

Comment: I believe this may be a little help for you on [this pdf](http://www.horrorlair.com/scripts/JeepersCreepers.pdf)

Comment: @natural its `Jepper Creeper 1` i am asking about second film, and I think there is no reference about the knife in the first movie

Comment: Oops, wrong one sorry, I referenced the wrong link, it's [this one](http://www.horrorlair.com/scripts/jeepers2.pdf) I was meant to link, not the first one.

Comment: its just the script of the movie, there is no reference to the story behind the knife or what it can do.

Comment: Tools: http://jeeperscreepers.wikia.com/wiki/Creeper

Comment: @Mary it will be great if you could put the required details from the link as answer

Comment: I dont think below answer is right for your question. I think knife acted like that because father had a history with creeper and its nothing like others have. So something may've triggered the knife/dagger to act as above. I think its because the connection between creeper and father

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Tools of the Creeper - wikia](http://jeeperscreepers.wikia.com/wiki/Creeper)

> The Creeper employs a variety of weapons in his pursuit for food. He
>   commonly carries daggers and throwing stars made from the flesh and
>   bones of his victims. He also uses a medieval battle axe in the first
>   film, which was destroyed after Trish hit him with her car. The
>   weapons he creates are shown to move of their own accord (or perhaps
>   return to their master) in the second film, where a knife flies across
>   a room under its own power, traveling through a leather lamp before
>   embedding into a nearby wall (a possible sign that they travel towards
>   flesh). In theory, it could be that the creeper has some sort of
>   psychic connection with his weapons (more specifically this knife).
>   Additionally, the father strategically decides to use it as a tip to
>   his harpoon to hunt the Creeper. Perhaps another fine example of the
>   Creeper's weapons and obsession with his victims would be a small
>   razor-disk like object that he used to flatten the school buses tires
>   in Jeepers Creepers 2, which appeared to have been crafted out of
>   Darry's flesh as it had his belly-button and rose tattoo on it. The
>   blades themselves are likely to be Darry's bones (it is unknown that
>   they are). Another example of his attachment to victims can be shown
>   with Billy Taggart. In the scene where Jack Taggart Sr. appears to be
>   sharpening a knife to use for the harpoon, notice the previously
>   mentioned knife that "mysteriously flew" across the room. On the
>   handle, there is cryptic, free-hand drawing of the creeper pursuing a
>   frightened Billy inside the cornfields.
>
> The Creeper also drives a very large, old-fashioned, rusted-looking
>   delivery truck which he uses to transport bodies and scare victims to
>   get a scent from their fear.